# How can I see whether a post I've read was changed, without looking through all of it?

Tags: support, bookmarks, last-activity

I recently started using Stack Overflow, and have come to use a few specific patterns to look up interesting questions. One is to look at recent ones with one of the tags that interest me. After reading an interesting question, I may mark it as favorite so I will find it again. So another pattern is to inspect my list of favorites to see if something interesting has happened. The only way I know now to be sure that I see all changes is to actually read through them, so I only do this about once a day. Is there a way to sort them according to when they were changed, or display this information in the list?

The changes I'm interested in are: new comments (I know that I am notified if someone answers a comment of mine using the @ construct), edits of the question, adding answers.

Comment: See the revision history or the timeline.

Comment: @user202729: that is only for edits. What the OP means is more like "Favorites", *except* that that *also* does not indicate new activity. We need a "Following" button, with a distinct function from "Favorites".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your favorites list by activity so that the posts with the most recent activity will be near the top.

Questions with activity since you last looked at the favorites list are also highlighted yellow.

Comment: I don't see anything highlighted in yellow. Could you describe how to get that?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Have activity on a post without checking your favorites, then check your favorites.

Comment: I still don't see anything in yellow, but the other suggestion was useful, because with "activity", the time of last modification is shown and not when it was created.